# MySQL Indexes on all column combinations

Tags: mysql, index, mysql-5.7, self-join

I have a table that basically represents the log of records

```sql
CREATE TABLE records
(
    id         varchar(36), -- uuid
    text       blob,
    user_id    bigint,
    cluster_id bigint,
    status_id  tinyint,
    session_id varchar,     -- uuid,
    type       tinyint,
    start_time timestamp,
    duration   int,
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id, start_time, id),
    KEY general_index (start_time, cluster_id, user_id, id),
    KEY endpoint_index (cluster_id, start_time, id)
);
```

The table is somehow large:

100 GB

10 GB index size

40 m records

Now the table is tuned to support filtering by `user_id`, `cluster_id` and `start_time`.
But I need to filter (and sort) efficiently by almost every column with different combinations.

Adding more and more indexes representing search patterns (e.g. `KEY general_index (start_time,duration,id)`) doesn't seem like a good long term solution.

Is there a best practice or something available for this for MySQL?
(unfortunately, using Elasticsearch or any other database is not an option)

First though I had is to have 1 PK index:

`PRIMARY KEY (start_time,id)`

and then many indexes that represent some search patterns like:

`KEY cluster_index (cluster_id, id)`,

`KEY user_index (user_id, id)`,

`KEY duration_index (duration, id)`,

`KEY status_index (status_id, id)`

When you need to query the date - just filter using appropriate index(es)

```
SELECT *
FROM records t
WHERE start_time >= {x}
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT id FROM records WHERE duration > 10000 -- supporting index duration_index
) t2 on t.id=t2.id
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT id FROM records WHERE user_id = 123 -- supporting index user_index
) t3 on t.id=t3.id
ORDER BY [...]
LIMIT 100
```

But that turns out to work pretty slow. Even if the solution above uses the correct index for a subquery it still has to do the HUGE join with `t`

Comment: Note you might see better performance query tuning rather than index tuning here. Instead of using full subqueries, it *can* be more relationally efficient to directly join to the Tables in your subqueries. Especially since you're doing all `INNER JOIN`s anyway, there's no need for subqueries. In fact, you really shouldn't need to be using joins at all here, and should just be able to directly apply your predicates to your single Table reference.

Comment: If I do a direct query, MySQL selects only 1 index. Thus, that index should contain most fields used (eg: `KEY example (start_time, user_id, duration, id)`) and given that I need to filter by at least 5 fields it resolves to many complex index combinations

Comment: That's actually not necessarily true, it can use multiple indexes or index operations as it deems most efficient. But I understand the rational in what you're doing as a way to try to influence it. In any case, you should be able to accomplish the same and possibly be better off relationally by removing the subqueries and directly `INNER JOIN` each instance instead.

Comment: For each separate query type (a combination of filtering conditions) select all column combinations which provides relatively high selectivity (approx. - 1% or less). Then select minimal combinations set which covers all gathered queries types, and create according indices. PS. Store UUID as BINARY(16), not as VARCHAR(36).

Comment: The best practice is to add indexes to support _specific_ queries. You cannot add indexes for every combination of columns, that would require _n_-factorial indexes for _n_ columns. It is likely not true that you need all combinations of indexes. In my experience, three or four indexes will help the majority of the queries you really need to execute.

Comment: You might like my presentation [How to Design Index, Really](https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/how-to-design-indexes-really) or the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ELR7-RdU9XU).

Answer (score 0):

**Miscellany Tips**

- Do not blindly add indexes.  Often they will go unused for mysterious reasons.
- Do list the important queries, then make indexes for them.  Eliminate duplicates.  (Give me the list, I'll design the indexes.)
- It may be useful to rethink the `PRIMARY KEY`.
- It is rarely useful to *start* a composite index with a date/datetime/timestamp.  Usually the optimal indexes *start* with columns tested with `=`.
- "filter (and sort) by almost every column with different combination" -- not practical.  A first cut is to list many 2-column indexes, then tack on a 3rd column to some of them.
- In InnoDB, the PK column(s) are implicitly tacked onto the end of each secondary index.
- Do not normalize flags; the added `JOINs` are too costly.  (I am guessing that `status_id` refers to a small number of possible values?)
- Your example of having subqueries delivering `ids`, is not likely to be efficient.  It is similar to what the Optimizer does with "Index merge" -- which is *rarely* used because of how inefficient it is.
- It looks like `text BLOB` averages over 2KB?  And it might actually be text, not blob?  If so, consider compressing/uncompressing (in the client).  This shrinks typical text by 3:1, thereby cutting the overall data size in half!  And probably there would be a slight overall CPU improvement.

**One query**

You provided hints of one query:

```
 WHERE start_time >= {x}
   AND duration > 10000
   AND user_id = 123
```

For that, I recommend two composite indexes, with the `user_id` *first*:

```
INDEX(user_id, duration),
INDEX(user_id, start_time)
```

The Optimizer can [usually] decide witch of these works better.  Because of the "range" test, a 3rd column would not benefit.

**ORDER BY**

The `ORDER BY` is important, too.  And so is `GROUP BY`.

If, for example, the above were followed by `ORDER BY start_time`, then the 2nd index would avoid a sort.

More on creating indexes:  [*Index Cookbook*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql)

**PRIMARY KEY; UUIDs**

40 million rows?  `PRIMARY KEY (user_id, start_time, id)`?  Or is it `PRIMARY KEY (start_time, id)`?  The 3-col version seems better, especially if a lot of queries include `WHERE user_id=123` and fetch multiple rows.

I'm surprised not to see `UNIQUE(id)` -- to make sure you don't have a dup UUID.

You could shrink the data by 1.6GB (plus some amount for the indexes) by shrinking the UUIDs into BINARY(16).  For 5.7, see my old blog: [*UUIDs*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/uuid) .  8.0 and MariaDB 10.7 have builtin most of my blog.

**PARTITIONing**

If you will be purging "old" data, then partitioning is much better than big deletes.  See [*Partition*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint) .  It will not, however help with most the performance of most `SELECTs`.  However, your one example has two ranges, one would be handled (somewhat) by "partition pruning" on `start_time`; then the other would benefit a suitable index:

```
PARTITION BY RANGE (TO_DAYS(start_time))...

PRIMARY KEY(user_id, start_time, id),
INDEX(user_id, duration)
```

Then the query would look at *some* partitions, using that secondary index to efficiently filter by `user_id` and `duration`.  That would build a temp table which would then be `ORDERed` and `LIMITed`.

I call that use of partitioning a "2D index".

Comment: Thank you for the answer! It's great!
I omitted some parts for simplicity. Yep, we use binary(16) for uuid and text is compressed.
`UNIQUE(id)` - is not needed since it's UUID.

`start_time between X and Y` - is present in 100% of queries, so it's tempting to include it everywhere.

So from what I get here, including it into PK is a bad idea.
Instead - add pairs (triples) like

`INDEX(user_id, duration, start_time),INDEX(user_id, start_time) ...etc`

Comment: What fraction of the range of dates is the `start_time` test?  For Partitioned tables, the partition key _must_ be in the PK.  For a non-partitioned table, it may or may not be beneficial to have `start_time` in the PK.  `INDEX(user_id, duration, start_time)` -- having two range-tested columns in an index is useless (unless it is "covering").